# How to reject unvalidated SSL client connections from the MongoDB server?

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I have setup a MongoDB server with a self-signed server certificate, and when I use the server validation method in Compass along with the CA certificate, it works well. However, I am still able to connect to the database if I select the “unvalidated” option in Compass, and I don’t want that. I want to reject any client connections that are not validating the server certificate. Is it possible to setup the server to do that? I have requireTLS setup in the config file, but Compass still lets unvalidated connections through.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue opened on MongoDB Jira: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-3369

TL;DR Compass allows connections with invalid certificates and it won't be fixed.